# Timestamp query in Azure

Tags: c#, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am really stuck in my query filter on Azure table storage.
May I know how to query with timestamp please?
When I query for partition key to 1005 alone, I am getting the complete table which I don't want.
When I added "and" condition with timestamp (tried with lots of formats but it is not returning anything. Code snippet below :

```
var lowerlimit = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-52).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

string dateRangeFilter = TableQuery.CombineFilters(
    TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "1005"),
    TableOperators.And,
    TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("TimeStamp", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, lowerlimit));
```

Answer (score 25):

I am able to use the Timestamp with Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage version 4.0.1.0.
Just and example

```
var query = TableQuery.CombineFilters(
            TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("Level", QueryComparisons.Equal, "ERROR"), 
            TableOperators.And, 
            TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("Timestamp", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-20).Date));

var query2 = TableQuery.CombineFilters(query,
            TableOperators.And, 
            TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("Timestamp", QueryComparisons.LessThanOrEqual, DateTimeOffset.Now));

var exQuery = new TableQuery<LogEntry>().Where(query2);

CloudTableClient tableClient = _storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference(_tableName);
var results = table.ExecuteQuery(exQuery).Select(ent => (T) ent).ToList();
```

Comment: Please do not query against timestamp. This will make execution very slow as it is not indexed.

Comment: Kurkula: Could one tell Azure to index the timestamp? It would be useful for a million different usecases.

Comment: @MrMambo007 No you cannot tell to index the timestamp.

Comment: @Kurkula, what if you were querying for a TableEntity by its PartitionKey and RowKey as well as the Timestamp being > last week? Would there be still be a slow down?

Comment: @benmccallum if you are querying by PartitionKey and RowKey than you shouldn't need to use timestamp, since you already have the unique item.  either way, just by adding the partitionkey to the query you are already improving performance, since the query won't do a full table scan anymore.

Comment: @jsucupira, the reason timestamp is useful is that say you have an Azure Function calling items from Table Storage which is caching the result of a long operation (unique by Partition and Row Keys) but the cache should only last one week. So my thinking is if you can include the timestamp > one week ago you save on transferring the item across the wire. As long as including timestamp in the query doesn't slow anything down, it seems optimal, particularly if the item in table storage is large and you pay for memory*time for Azure Functions. Yay/nay?

Answer (score 10):

Timestamp can be used to query rows in Azure Table Storage.

However, you will need to use `TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate` instead of `TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition`. For any DateTime column, `TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate` must be used.

From your code sample, change `GenerateFilterCondition` to `GenerateFilterConditionForDate` for Timestamp filter:

```
var lowerlimit = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-52).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

string dateRangeFilter = TableQuery.CombineFilters(
    TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "1005"),
    TableOperators.And,
    TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("TimeStamp", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, lowerlimit));
```

Comment: how can i retrieve most latest record using TimeStamp ?

Answer (score 7):

Property names are case-sensitive. It should be Timestamp and not TimeStamp.

Answer (score 5):

If this is a diagnostics table (e.g. WADLogsTable) I suggest you convert your timestamp to a partition key, then query on that.  This would avoid a full table scan since it is an indexed column.  Conversion is simple, just prepend "0" to the ticks.

```
var lowerlimitPartitionKey = DateTimeToPartitionKey(lowerlimit);

// Now query PartitionKey >= lowerlimitPartitionKey
...
```

where

```
private string DateTimeToPartitionKey(DateTime dt)
{
    return "0" + dt.Ticks;
}
```