# Azure filtering time stamp with date containing short date

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I am trying to filter code with a datepicker on UI which gives me data in 'mm/dd/yyyy' format and on change i call service which has data as time stamp. How can I filter data in the below code where date is equal to **any time in the selected day**.

Ex:

```
string filterDate ="3/28/2016";
TableQuery<MyEntity> query = new TableQuery<MyEntity>()
            .Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("Timestamp", QueryComparisons.Equal, Convert.ToDateTime(filterDate)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine two filters together:

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(filterDate);

var query = TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("Timestamp", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, dt);

var query2 = TableQuery.CombineFilters(query,
        TableOperators.And, 
        TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("Timestamp",    QueryComparisons.LessThan, dt.AddDays(1)));
```

You could check [DateTime.AddDays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Timestamp query in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325445/timestamp-query-in-azure/32329089#32329089) for more details.