# RowKey pattern of Azure SQL Audit logs

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-table-storage, audit-logging

I have configured Azure SQL server to store audit logs in a Storage account. It has created a Table called `SQLDBAuditLogsMYDBNAME`. That is fine and I can also look into the table and see the logs.

The problem is that usable filtering can be applied only on PartitionKey and RowKey (not Timestamp, which is what I need). PartitionKey contains server and database name, so it is of no help. However, RowKeys are in a particular order and it seems to be related to Timestamp (second part after the asterisk is a GUID). Unfortunately, I am not able to find out how to guess the RowKey based on a DateTime.

You can see three value pairs here:

```
| Timestamp                | RowKey                                  |
| 2017-04-13T15:30:00.630Z | 2519102033993698531*7588f70d-0b4e-49... |
| 2017-04-13T16:15:00.615Z | 2519102006993841015*1667d291-bbef-40... |
| 2017-04-13T17:15:01.255Z | 2519101970987444854*6f4dca8f-e81a-4a... |
```

As you can see, numbers are in a Descending order.

I have tried many combinations (e.g., subtract the number from `long.MaxValue` and then take it as Ticks and so on) but with no success.

Can you see a way to get proper RowKey range from date range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can you see a way to get proper RowKey range from date range?

The relationship is:  `DateTime.MaxValue-TimeStamp=Rowkey`

Because TimeStamp is a divisors, some Milliseconds is ignored in TimeStamp. So, you could use the DateTime.MaxValue-RowKey to achieve a Fuzzy query.
The following code using the first group data that you provided.

```
var ticks = DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - 2519102033993698531;
DateTime datetime = new DateTime(ticks);
Console.WriteLine(datetime.ToString());
```

The screen shot:

[image]

It is almost the same with the TimeStamp. Or you could use this [link](http://www.tickstodatetime.com/) to check what the result that convert ticks to datetime.

> The problem is that usable filtering can be applied only on PartitionKey and RowKey (not Timestamp, which is what I need).

However, as you mentioned, you think you only could filter table storage with PartitionKey and RowKey.

AFAIK, **you could also use TimeStamp to filter table storage**. For more detail about how to filter, you could refer to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325445/timestamp-query-in-azure).

Comment: Thank you, Joey, that is exactly what I wanted. For some reason, DateTime.MaxValue didn't come to my mind - it seems so obvious now.

Comment: I can filter by TimeStamp, but it is very slow (there is no index on Timestamp). That's why I want to filter by RowKey.