# "Syntax error at position 20 in Timestamp" Azure table storage query problems

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to pull out some data from our table storage in our office. I can get every type of query to work except the timestamp ones. they keep giving me a HTTP error 400 bad request. when inspecting it the exact error text is

> "*Syntax error at position 20 in 'Timestamp eq
>   2018-06-04T12:05:31.9150000Z'.
>   RequestId:3949e07b-b002-003f-59f8-065461000000
>   Time:2018-06-18T11:38:28.7307368Z*".

My code for accessing the specific data is; 
`var lowerlimit = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-20);`

```
TableQuery<LogEntity> query = new TableQuery<LogEntity>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("Timestamp", QueryComparisons.GreaterThan, lowerlimit));
```

as an example this code works;

```
TableQuery<LogEntity> query = new TableQuery<LogEntity>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("Level", QueryComparisons.Equal, "Warn"));
```

i havent been able to find anyone with the same problem as me, so i hope you can help me out! thanks in advance!

```
*edit* here is the full code

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure; // Namespace for CloudConfigurationManager
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage; // Namespace for StorageAccounts
using Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table; // Namespace for Table storage types
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace DataPullingViregoLog
{
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var lowerlimit = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-20);

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
            CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

        CloudTableClient tableClient = 
        storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        // Create the CloudTable object that represents the "people" table.
        CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("{dbname}");


        TableQuery<LogEntity> query = new TableQuery<LogEntity> 
        ().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("Timestamp", 
        QueryComparisons.GreaterThan, lowerlimit));




        IEnumerable<LogEntity> table2 = table.ExecuteQuery(query);

        var listOfEntities = new List<LogEntity>();
        foreach (LogEntity entity in table2)
        {
            listOfEntities.Add(entity);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}\t{2}\t{3}", entity.PartitionKey, 
            entity.RowKey,
            entity.Level, entity.MessageWithLayout);

        }

        var convertedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listOfEntities, 
        Formatting.Indented);
    }

}

internal class LogEntity : TableEntity
{

    public LogEntity(string PartitionKey, string Rowkey, DateTime Timestamp)
    {
        this.PartitionKey = PartitionKey;
        this.RowKey = RowKey;
        this.Timestamp = Timestamp;

    }

    public LogEntity() { }
    public string LogTimeStamp { get; set; }
    public string Level {get;set;}
    public string LoggerName { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string MessageWithLayout { get; set; }
    public string MachineName { get; set; }
    public long LogTimeTicks { get; set; } 
    public string Exception { get; set; }
}
```

/Rasmus

Comment: Is it a custom column or is it the standard Timestamp column? Because that one it a `DateTimeOffset`, Have you tried changing your `lowerlimit` to that? [This answer uses DateTimeOffset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325445/timestamp-query-in-azure)

Comment: It throws the same exception with the same error code. I have no knowledge if its a standard, But when comparing the strings 1 to 1 they look completely the same.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue that you mentioned on my side. I test it with the lastest [WindowsAzure.Storage 9.20](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/) version with Azure storage account. If possible, please use the latest Azure storage  and try it again.

Comment: It's weird, since per my understanding the query string should be like: Timestamp eq datetime'2018-06-04T12:05:31.9150000Z'

Comment: the date i send is 2018-06-04T12:05:31.9150000Z whereas a date in the database looks like 2018-06-04T12:07:01.371Z . as you can see the only difference is in the trailing zeros. Can this be the issue? As i understand it at the moment the problem is the request made from my code. which evidently has a mistake at space 20. @ZhaoxingLu-Microsoft are you saying the ' ' should be around the date?

Comment: @Rasraa The format should be datetime'{Some UTC time string}'

Comment: So i did as you asked @TomSun and i updated my nuget packages. This however gave me a problem even higher up. i am now Recieving Could not load type 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Auth.Protocol.IAuthenticationHandler' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common, Version=9.4.0.0. i had trouble with the newest packages before so thats why i downgraded.

Comment: @Rasraa Please share more code if possible. The error message shared by you is "Timestamp eq", but the source code is QueryComparisons.GreaterThan, which don't match at all. The generated query string should have been "Timestamp gt" for QueryComparisons.GreaterThan.

Comment: @ZhaoxingLu-Microsoft how do i feed that exact string into the code? it is my understanding that this is a TableQuery. I dont see how that would accept a string, unless you want me to do some workaround.

Comment: I meant the error message didn't really come from the code you shared, since they don't match. Please share more code and point out where the exception was thrown.

Comment: @ZhaoxingLu-Microsoft i've added the full code. before the exception was thrown at  IEnumerable<LogEntity> table2 = table.ExecuteQuery(query);. now with the new error, it is thrown at CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient(). (because the nuget was updated,

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I assume that you are using [Azure cosmos table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-table-dotnet) ([Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table/)) SDK to operate the Azure storage account.

If you are operating the Azure storage table, please use the [WindowsAzure.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/),
it is different  from you mentioned library.

I recommand that you could create a new project with [WindowsAzure.Storage 9.20](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/) installed then it should work correctly.

[image]

Comment: Hey Tom thanks for your answer. According to the guide i am using from microsoft: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-dotnet) _Developers already familiar with Azure Table storage may have used the WindowsAzure.Storage package in the past. It is recommended that all new table applications use the Azure Storage Common Library and the Azure Cosmos DB Table Library, however the WindowsAzure.Storage package is still supported. If you use the WindowsAzure.Storage library, include Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table in your using statements._

Comment: @Rasraa Azure Storage Common Library is still preview version. Based on my knowledge, we can't use the CosomsDB table library to operate Azure storage table currently.

Comment: As i am now using the correct libary (tableStorage) instead some of the code (mainly `CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();` doesnt work, because it isnt supported by that libary. Do you by chance know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Based on my understanding, you are trying to use the Azure storage connectionstring to create Azure Cosmos TableClient. So you get the error information. If still want to use that library, you could have a try create an Azure Cosoms table API to test it.

Comment: I am just following the guide that microsoft has published. They state that this works for both types. I assume that you're correct that it doesn't. given my current code and what i am trying to accomplish, what would i modify to make it work with tablestorage instead of the current code. i cannot change the database that is in question as this is made for a customer.

Answer (score 0):

So i found out that another libary is needed which is not shown in any of microsofts guides. this is how my final code looks like. Thanks for your assistance! apperently the only thing needed is `using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table; 
using Microsoft.Azure;`