# How to compare default Timestamp property in a cosmos DB table

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-tables

The cosmos DB table entry manages a default `Timestamp` property for each table operation. While I am trying to query last updated entries based on the same time stamp field the result is not behaving as expected. The TableQuery looks like below:

```
TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("Timestamp",
                QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual,
                timestamp)
```

Where `timestamp` is a `DateTimeOffset` object. I am getting 0 rows retrieved even with rows existing in the table with the `Timestamp` column holding a higher value. What is missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Data in my table.*

[image]

*Query params.*

[image]

*Result.*

[image]

```
var query = TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("Timestamp", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-10).Date);
var exQuery = new TableQuery<CustomerEntity>().Where(query);
var results0 = sourcetable.ExecuteQuery(exQuery).ToList();
//var results1 = sourcetable.ExecuteQuery(exQuery).Select(ent => (CustomerEntity)ent).ToList();
```

Comment: For more details, you can view [related posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325445/timestamp-query-in-azure).